# $2^n+3^n= m^k$ imply $k=1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

If $m,n,k$ are natural numbers such that $$2^n+3^n= m^k$$ where demonstrate that $k=1.$

I tried to prove that divides equal amount left 5 but does not divide by 25 and we did. Maybe someone else has the idea. Thank you!

Comment: The left does not have to divide $5$ in general.

Comment: Take $n=2$, then $5\nmid 2^2+3^2$.

Comment: Fermat's last theroem says the following: $$\text{ Any prime factor of } n\nmid k $$

Answer (score 2):

For $k=2$ this has been shown, among other papers, in [More on a Diophantine equation $2^x+3^y=m^2$](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2013-84-2/11/11.pdf). It has only three solutions, namely $(x,y)=(0,1),(3,0),(4,2)$. In no case we have $x=y$. Hence we solved the question for all even $k$. For $k$ odd, it follows that $n=k$ (I cannot find the reference right now, but I will try). Then, by Fermat, this is impossible.